# Review - audit questions take longer to load?

Tags: support, review-audits

I don't know if it's just me but it seems that when I review, it takes a bit longer to load an audit item as opposed to a real item needing reviewing. Since I noticed that, it's been like that in most cases and it's sort of giving away that it's an audit.

Comment: This has been mentioned before, but it isn't always audits.  I've seen regular posts take a while too.

Comment: That may be true. Still, it just makes me extra careful on those long loading ones...

Comment: +1, can reproduce consistently for suggested edits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Still, it just makes me extra careful on those long loading ones

If you need to take extra time and care over *audit* reviews then you're not spending enough time on real reviews.
If anything, arguably, the *real* reviews (not audit) warrant extra time as they're more important. As whatever action you choose on a real review has an affect on someone's answer, question, mod time, etc, and not just a fake one for a test that the system auto handles.

I've spotted an audit review once or twice, and when (for example) it's a non-answer needing flagging as "not an answer" the only difference for me was I did the audit quicker, because there is no love to potentially give to the non-answer like commenting to try to get the answerer to change it, and so I just quickly click flag.

But whether real or audit, or they take extra time to load or not, I think the point is to not try to ascertain when a review is an audit, or spend different time over one or another, and instead just action all reviews with consistency and accuracy and any you do will be fine.

Comment: I do take care. But if people get warned, audits make less sense. And yes, if I spot what I think is an audit, I click the flag straight away as it doesn't do anything on just clicking.